# why doesn't onclick function work when I add it dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I am adding an html tag to the page

```
<div id="asd" >
        <button id="gaga" onclick="onClick()"></button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                        function onClick() {
                            console.log(":(");
                            const element = document.getElementById('asd');
                            if (element) {
                                element.remove();
                           }
                       }
                    </script>
    </div>
```

After I loaded the page and dynamically added this tag through the servlet, I try to click on the button but an error appears in the console:

[image]

I was thinking of adding this tag and script to it via a servlet, but for some reason the browser does not see this function on the page

EDIT:
I upload the code to the page via websocket (on the first page I wait for the button to appear, and on the second page I create it with a get request on the first page)

Servlet code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyAIV.png)

Comment: Scripts aren't executed when you assign to `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @Barmar — What does `innerHTML` have to do with it? They said it was being added by a servlet (i.e. server-side Java code) although they failed to include it. The JS they did include doesn't use `innerHTML` at all.

Comment: @Quentin I assumed that the server is adding it dynamically using `innerHTML`, since it matches the symptom.

Comment: @Quentin The HTML/JS they show is what is added by the servlet. They didn't post the servlet itself.

Comment: @Barmar — They HTML/JS they show works. If its added by a servlet then it won't use `innerHTML` because that's not a servlet API. Maybe they're making an Ajax call to a servlet and then using innerHTML to add the result, but they haven't said that. The question really needs a [mcve].

Comment: They said the servlet is adding the div dynamically. So it's adding both the `<button>` and the `<script>`. The script is ignored, so the `onClick` function never gets defined.

Comment: @Quentin I now realize that I was thinking "bookmarklet" when they said "servlet". But a servlet runs on the server, not the client, so I'm not sure how it would add HTML to the DOM.

Comment: Please show how you're adding the code using the servlet.

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. They can't be copy/pasted to build test cases, don't show up in searches, may be blocked for users on networks without access to some other websites, and are invisible to screen readers / braille keyboards / etc. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself.

Answer (score -2):

because the browser is not aware of the newly added elements. When you add the HTML tag dynamically, the browser needs to reparse the DOM (Document Object Model) to recognize the new elements. This process takes some time, and until the DOM has been reparsed, the browser will not be able to recognize the onclick attribute on the newly added button.

To fix this problem, you can use event delegation to attach the onclick event handler to a parent element that is already present in the DOM. This way, the browser will not need to reparse the DOM every time you add a new button, and the onclick event handler will still work.

```html
<div id="asd">
  <button id="gaga"></button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('asd').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.id === 'gaga') {
        console.log(":(");
        const element = document.getElementById('asd');
        if (element) {
          element.remove();
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

With this code, the onclick event handler will be attached to the parent div element, and the browser will not need to reparse the DOM every time you add a new button. The event handler will still work, and you will be able to remove the newly added button without any errors.

Comment: "When you add the HTML tag dynamically, the browser needs to reparse the DOM (Document Object Model)" — They said they were using a servlet (i.e. doing this server side) not with client-side JS / DOM.

Comment: There's no `addEventListener()`, they're using inline `onclick=` in the HTML.